# How to Pause Responsive Slides in Shopify

Tags: jquery, css, shopify, responsive

I am looking to find out, how I can add a pause on hover feature as well as links on the slides within my responsive banners. I have used the following jquery on my site and this works fine as the slides change every couple of seconds.

responsiveslides.com

Now when I edit the following code:

```
<script>
      $(function() {
        $(".rslides").responsiveSlides();
      });
  </script>
```

to

```
<script>
      $(function() {
        $(".rslides").responsiveSlides({
          pause: true
      });
  </script>
```

but this doesn't work and I am not too sure why.

If somebody could please help.

Comment: You are missing the closing bracket and parenthesis on `$(".rslides").responsiveSlides({ pause:true });`

Comment: have the closing bracket and parenthesis on the next line, tried it all on 1 line but makes no difference..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to close `responsiveSlides`

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $(".rslides").responsiveSlides({
            pause: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank u jrbedard, having looked at your first answer, it was my misunderstanding.